# Sampling from multivariate truncated normal?

Tags: r, random-generation, truncated-normal-distribution

I try to implement [this procedure](https://pdfhost.io/v/mtUFt5CPS_document). Edit: I report the mathematical steps here:

Let $Y \sim TN_d(0,\Sigma, -l, +\infty)$ if $Y = Z | Z \ge -l$ with $Z \sim N_d(0, \Sigma)$ i.e. a multivariate normal distribution with dimension $d$, mean vector $0$ and variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma$ truncated below $-l$.

Let $L = chol(\Sigma)$ that is $LL^T = \Sigma$ and $L$ is a lower triangular matrix so
$$
Y \ge -l \Rightarrow LX \ge -l \, \, , X_i \overset{i.i.d.}\sim N(0,1) \, \, .
$$
So we can write $LX \ge -l$ as:
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
 L_{1,1}X_1& \ge -l_1 \, , \\
 L_{2,1}X_1& + L_{2,2}X_2 \ge -l_2 \, , \\
 &\dots \\
 L_{d,1}X_1& + L_{d,2}X_2 + \dots + L_{d,d}X_d \ge -l_d \, .
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}

That is
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  X_1& \ge -\frac{l_1}{L_{1,1}} \, , \\
  X_2& \ge -\frac{l_2 + L_{2,1}X_1}{L_{2,2}} \, , \\
  &\dots \\
  X_d& \ge -\frac{l_d + L_{d,1}X_1 + L_{d,2}X_2 + \dots + L_{d,d-1}X_{d-1}}{L_{d,d}} \, .
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}

So we can sample
$$
X_i \vert X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{i-1} \sim TN\left(0,1, -\frac{l_i + L_{i,1}X_1 + L_{i,2}X_2 + \dots + L_{i,i-1}X_{i-1}}{L_{i,i}}, +\infty \right) \, \, ,
$$

where $V_0 \sim TN(\mu, \sigma^2, a, b)$ if $V_0=V_1 \vert a \le V_1 \le b$ and $V_1 \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Finally we set $Y = LX$.

So I try to implement the procedure above with the following R code by using package TruncatedNormal:

```r
# Setup
set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
d = 3 # set dimension of multivariate distribution
Sigma = matrix(rWishart(1, d, diag(16,d)), d)/d # generate a variance-covariance matrix
l = rcauchy(d) # generate lower constraint
cholSigma = t(chol(Sigma)) # compute cholesky factor as lower triangular matrix
nsim = 1e+6 # set number of simulations
```

So a this point I have $d$, $\Sigma$ and $l$ for $X \sim TN_d(0, \Sigma, -l, +\infty)$ and a lower triangular matrix $L$ such that $\Sigma = LL^T$. I want generate a number of $10^6$ simulations from $X$, so i create a matrix `x` where each column is an indipendent sample of $X$. Therefore the number of rows of `x` is `d=3` and the numbers of columns of `x` is `nsim = 1e+6` i.e. $10^6$.

```r
# Create matrix x
x = matrix(nrow = d, ncol = nsim)
```

Now I generate the values for the first component of $X$, say $X_1$, with the constraint reported in the link above that is
$$
X_1 \sim TN \left(0,1,-\frac{l_1}{L_{11}}, +\infty\right) \, \, .
$$

Note that from $X_1$ I generate $10^6$ realizations in order to fill the entire first row of `x` indeed `TruncatedNormal::rtnorm(n, mu, sd, lb, ub)` generate `n` i.i.d. draws from an univariate normal random variable with mean `mu` and standard devation `sd` with the constrains that the variables are greater than `lb` and less than `ub`.

```r
# Update first row of x based on formula in link
x[1,] = TruncatedNormal::rtnorm(n = nsim, mu = 0, sd = 1, 
                                 lb = -l[1]/cholSigma[1,1], 
                                 ub = +Inf)
```

Once I have $X_1$ I can generate the other components of $X$, say $X_i \, \, i = 2,3,\dots,d$, with the following representation:
$$
X_i|X_1,X_2, \dots, X_{i-1} \sim TN\left(0,1,-\frac{l_i+L_{i,1}X_1+L_{i,2}X_2+\dots+L_{i,i-1}X_{i-1}}{L_{i,i}}, +\infty\right) \, \, .
$$
Furthermore I highlight that in this case tha value of `n` in `TruncatedNormal:rtnorm(n,mu,sd,lb,ub)` is `n=1` because the argument `lb` is a vector of length equal to `nsim`. So in this way the function samples one draw for each value of the vector `lb`.

I highlight that `(l[i] + cholSigma[i,1:(i-1)] %*% x[1:(i-1),])` is $v^{(i)}$ equal to
$$
v^{(i)} = l_i + \hat{L}_{i.}\hat{X} \,\, ,
$$
where $\hat{L}_{i.}$ is a row vector of dimension $d$ composed by
$$
\hat{L}_{i.} = \left[L_{i,1}, L_{i,2}, \dots, L_{i,i-1}, 0, \dots, 0\right] 
$$
and $\hat{X}$ is `x`, the matrix where I store the random numbers generated from $X$, let $\hat{X}_{.j}$ the $j$-th column of $\hat{X}$, that is `x`, so the $j$-th component of $v^{(i)}$, say $v^{(i)}_j$, is

$$
v^{(i)}_j = l_i + \hat{L}_{i.}\hat{X}_{.j} = l_i + \sum_{h=1}^{i-1}L_{i,h}X_{h,j} \, \,
$$
since $\hat{X}$ have $10^6$ columns $v^{(i)}$ is a vector of length $10^6$.

Finally `-(l[i] + cholSigma[i,1:(i-1)] %*% x[1:(i-1),]) / cholSigma[i,i]` is
$$
-\frac{v^{(i)}}{L_{i,i}}
$$
that is a simple scalar for a vector product, so the lenght of `lb` is equal to $10^6$, i.e. `nsim = 1e+6`.

```r
# Update the other rows of x based on formula in link
for(i in 2:d){
  x[i,] = TruncatedNormal::rtnorm(n = 1, mu = 0, sd = 1, 
                       lb = -(l[i] + cholSigma[i,1:(i-1)] %*% 
                       x[1:(i-1),]) / cholSigma[i,i], 
                                  ub = rep(+Inf, nsim))
}
```

Finally, since $Y = LX$ i set $\hat{Y} = L\hat{X}$

```r
y0 = cholSigma%*%x
```

For more details I report the values of $\Sigma$ and $l$ generated in the first step.

```r
Sigma
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  5.031011  6.591142 -4.809947
[2,]  6.591142 28.714024 -9.351387
[3,] -4.809947 -9.351387  5.118928

l
[1] 138.34760311  -1.22737450  -0.02543323
```

Also I use the function `mvrandn` for sampling from multivariate truncated normal in order to compare the results.

```r
y1 = TruncatedNormal::mvrandn(l = -l, u = rep(+Inf, d), Sig = Sigma, 
     n = nsim)
```

So I obtaing the following empirical mean of the marginal distributions of $X$:

```r
rowMeans(y0)
[1] 9.933312e-05 4.569716e+00 5.042449e-01

rowMeans(y1)
[1] -1.7249942  3.1711154  0.8770725
```

But I do one million of draws, so I think something is wrong in my algorithm since there are large differences in the mean estimator. What is the problem?

Edit: thank you @whuber for the answer, I try to explain with more details my code, I hope in this way you can help me.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is going wrong because (i) the problem is likely in your code but (ii) you don't clearly describe what that code is intended to do.  As far as truncated normals go, my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/158008/919 illustrates effective ways to examine and test your results.  It also offers an independent way to generate truncated multivariate normal values.

Comment: Although I voted to reopen this question, your notation is still a little mysterious.  In particular, how exactly are you truncating the multivariate Normal? To a rectangle?  And what exactly do the arguments of "$TN_d$" mean?  Guessing that one of them might be related to the variances, you seem to be relying on an (incorrect) assumption that all the conditional distributions have the same variances--but most likely I just don't understand your notation. (Your key reference goes to a site many people might not trust and it doesn't deliver anything useful: I get a blank document.)

Comment: I'm sorry for the blank document. It is a my pdf that I have hosted in an external site, I see it correctly, I don't know the reason why you do not see it. Since without pdf it is very difficult to understand my notation I will provide the mathematical steps of pdf directly in my question. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Are you really only interested in a 3D problem?

Comment: @jbowman Not necessarily, I provided an example with dimension ```d=3``` only for the sake of simplicity (and for time computing since I sampled 2 times $10^6$ i.i.d. draws). Mathematical steps should be valid for any value of $d$ but for some reasons my code does not work in the example.