# Monte Carlo Approximation on integral of Gaussian pdf on Convex Domain

Tags: monte-carlo, approximation, integral

I have hard time on estimating the following integral on convex domain ($\mathcal D$) using Monte-Carlo approximation.

$$a = \int_{\mathcal D} dx f(x;\mu,\Sigma) $$

where $x \in \mathbb R^d$ and $f$ is Gaussian pdf. Note that this integral might not have a closed-form since $\mathcal D$ can be, for example, intersection of three disks. My naive approach is to sample $x_i \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \Sigma)$ and then verify whether it belongs to $\mathcal D$. If not, I discard it. After sampling for $N$ times, I have $n$ undiscarded samples $\{x_j\}_n$ that can be used for estimation,

$$\hat a \approx \frac 1 n\sum_{x_j} f(x_j;\mu,\Sigma)$$

However I am not sure if such approach can still yield consistent and unbiased estimator of $a$. If not, how can we do good estimation of $a$ in practice? Pointers to existing Python or R library can be helpful, thanks.

Comment: As a general problem, this can be difficult even for $d=1,$ because the expected rejection rate can be arbitrarily close to 100%.  As an example of what specific cases might look like and of just one (out of myriad) ways of addressing them, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157963.

Comment: You need to find a manageable region $\mathcal R$containing $\mathcal D \subset\mathcal R$ and to simulate from an importance distribution restricted to this region.